# How to create a summary of issues by rule from SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I have downloaded the Codescan bundler and successfully ran an analysis.  I would like to create a summary report which is counts the number of issues by Rule i.e.

```
Rule Name                       Count
Reflected Javascript XSS        15
@Future Methods inside Loops    20
.........
```

The codescan bundler ships with Sonarqube 6.3 and with this version the reporting and ability to export to excel has been remomved.  I have used the web API - http://localhost:59001/api/issues/search?p=1&statuses=OPEN,CONFIRMED,REOPENED,RESOLVED,CLOSED, but this only returns 10000 rows

How can I get the number of issues for each rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "break down" your request into several smaller ones, so that you can be sure, that you will not get more than 10000 issues at once.

For example you could query all the rules you are interested in one by one.

Comment: Thank you and that is what i have done.  I am using the quality profile to get all of the rules being run, then looping through each rule, call the issues api with the rules param.  This has worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

10,000 records is the hard limit set in the web services. You will not be able to go past this.